# cannot resolve FirebaseListAdapter<T>

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listadapter

I am trying to develop chat application. I am getting an error while defining firebaseList adapter. Below is my code for firebaseList adapter and am getting error as FireBaseListAdaper() in fireBaseListAdapter cannot be applied :optional parameters, Actual Arguments

```
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> fbListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this,ChatMessage.class,R.layout.message,FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference())
```

Below are my imports :

```
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: is it resolved @kamilhussain?

Answer (score 0):

This is the example in [the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview):

```
FirebaseListOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Chat>()
        .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
        .build();

FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Chat model, int position) {
        // Bind the Chat to the view
        // ...
    }
};
```